# $\int f(y)e^{-y^2} e^{2xy}\,dy$, to prove $f=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that, if $f \in S(\mathbb{R})$, where $S(\mathbb{R})$ defines  Schwartz's space, and
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(y)e^{-y^2}e^{2xy} \, dy =0,$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f=0$

I don't know how start , it occurs to me some property of convolution functions , Greetings..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(y) e^{-y^2} e^{2xy}\, dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) e^{-(y^2-2xy+x^2)} e^{x^2}\,dy = e^{x^2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(y) e^{-(x-y)^2} \,dy.
$$
Since $e^{x^2}\ne0$, the above can be $0$ only if that last integral is $0$.  A routine substitution the tells us that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x-y) e^{-y^2}\,dy=0.
$$
i.e.
$$
(f*g)(x)=0 \text{ for all }x,
$$
where $g(y)=e^{-y^2}$.  This implies a relationship involving Fourier transforms:
$$
\widehat f(t) \cdot \widehat {\,g\,}(t) = 0\text{ for all }t. 
$$
Now recall that the Fourier transform of a Schwartz function is always another Schwartz function (which I think has a lot to do with why those functions are used) and the Fourier transform of a Gaussian function is a Gaussian function.  And since the value of a Gaussian function is never $0$, all of the values of the other function must be $0$.

Comment: Wonderful solution!

Comment: @Moya : Thank you. ${}\qquad{}$